# Finite morphism vs morphism of finite degree

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism of projective varieties (integral schemes of finite type) over a field $k$.
If $f$ is dominant, then $f$ induces a field extension $K(Y)\to K(X)$ of function fields. We call $f$ finite whenever this extension is. The *degree of f* is then defined to be the dimension of $K(X)$ as a vector space over $K(Y)$.

My question is this: what are the possible implications between $f$ having finite degree and $f$ being a finite morphism? I think that $f$ having finite degree would imply that all its fibers are finite, which in turn implies that $f$ is finite, but I'm not sure how to go about this. For the other direction, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: So are you asking if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a dominant morphism of projective varieties, then $f$ is quasi-finite if and only if $f$ is finite?

Comment: @KentaS No, what you're suggesting follows from $f$ being proper in this case. My question concerns "finite" vs "of finite degree."

Comment: What you here call finite is usually called **generically finite**.

Comment: @Sasha Oh I meant finite in the sense that any open affine cover $Spec B_i$ of $Y$ has affine preimages $Spec A_i$, and the restriction of $f$ to these affine opens realizes each $B_i$ as a finitely generated module over $A_i$. I should have been more prudent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finite implies finite degree, but finite degree does not imply finite (nor quasi-finite).

Finite implies finite degree: let $\eta_X$, $\eta_Y$ be the generic points of $X$ and $Y$, thought of as the spectra of their function fields. Then the fiber product of $i:\eta_Y\to Y$ and $f$ is a finite scheme over $\eta_Y$ which must be $\eta_X$ by integrality of $X$, so $K(Y)\subset K(X)$ is finite.

Finite degree does not imply finite: consider a blowup of $\Bbb P^2$ in a closed point $P$. Then this is a birational morphism (hence of degree 1) but not finite.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The blowup example is a very convenient one, but it got me thinking: does a counterexample still exist if $X$ and $Y$ were to coincide?

Comment: If they're normal, then Zariski's main theorem says that such a map is an isomorphism. An answer for the non-normal case doesn't immediately come to mind.